# JSON: InlineEditField for choice columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

When using the JSON function "inlineEditField" for a choice column I can click the entry in the list and then it dissapears. Afterwards the value is cleared.

My code is:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "inlineEditField": "[$columnname]",
    "txtContent": "[$columnname]"
}
```

`[$columnname]` has the correct internal name.

How must the JSON be changed to have a dropdown list of the valid values?

Comment: Can you check the choice column settings once, are you using "Drop-Down Menu" option or "Radio buttons" option under **Display choices using** setting for choice column? Try using drop-down menu option. Let me know if it works for you!

Comment: It's set to drop-down. I tried both options neither is working.

Comment: Are you using Edge or Chrome browser? I have seen similar issue faced by another users. I think this is bug from Microsoft end with latest Edge & SharePoint updates.

Answer (score 1):

If you are here with the [Object object] problem with inline edit fields.

Please try this for your JSON column formatting: "txtContent" : "@currentField.lookupValue"

Adding .lookupValue should help for lookup columns. The properties .title and .email can work with person inline edit fields.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug from Microsoft end with latest Edge browser & SharePoint updates.

I will suggest you to raise a support ticket with Microsoft directly and report this behavior. Follow, [Get M365 support - online support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/get-help-support?view=o365-worldwide#online-support)

Also, instead of using [internal name of your SharePoint choice column](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/), you can use `@currentField` like:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "inlineEditField": "@currentField",
  "txtContent": "@currentField"
}
```

I did few tests from my end and it is working fine for me when I have selected **Drop-Down Menu** under **Display choices using** option in choice column settings (Using both Edge - v112.0.1722.48 and Chrome browser):

[image]

**Similar thread**: [InlineFieldEdit on choice column not working anymore?](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/inlinefieldedit-on-choice-column-not-working-anymore/m-p/3802111)

Comment: It is not working when selecting "Radio buttons" option under Display choices using setting. List of choice options open and disappears immediately for me.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue and I suspect that assigning a default value at the moment of the field creation causes this glitch. I created a new choice field with the default value set to 'None' and the inline editing now behaves as expected. Not sure, might just be a fluke.

Comment: That might be an issue. As the choice field only had 3 values I ended up using buttons for each option  to set the values to the field. Works also.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue where if the field is not visible on your Input form, the inlineEditField will not function properly. Text field value will be erase, multi-choice fields will quickly blink and disappear, etc. To workaround to keep the field hidden on your Input form is to first add it to the input form, then add a conditional formula that will always return False like =if(1== 2, 'true', 'false')